# Does Ellie got a magic 'Were done here' sense?

Tags: the-last-of-us-2

Last of us 2 is, in parts, an open world game.

When you go check out a location, Ellie seems to have a magic sense that she got everything she needed in that location.

Usually this UI is completely separate of the game, but since in Last of Us 2 Ellie does have a map in her hand where she checks complete locations that feels like that check might be 'I checked the area' and not 'I've got everything I need here'. I've got a check at every location I went at this point, so that gives weight to my theory that the criteria for checking off a location is pretty lax. I don't believe I was always perfect in clearing out places.

So what triggers the 'I'm done here' check? Is it all ressources? All items needed for hints later (codes, story beats, notes, etc.) or just going in and leaving counts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both Ellie and Abby will make a small remark if you kill all the enemies in an area - indicating it's safe to move freely. It does not necessarily relate to looing all items from a zone as your character may not have capacity to pick up all ammo or rags, or whatnot.

It's also noteworthy that more enemies may spawn in an area even after these remarks are made, under specific circumstances. As an example, the optional bank location from Seattle Day 1 can generate two remarks - one after defeating all enemies in the lobby, and a second remark after defeating the newly spawned enemies once Ellie grabs the shotgun.